# What protocol is inside my packet? (Ns3)

Tags: arp, ns-3

I **need to know if the packets that my Rx is getting are ARP** in order to discard them for my process.

I've looked into the manual and the tutorial of ns3, but I found nothing in both of them about which protocol is inside a packet.

**Is there any function or part in ns3 which let me know the protocol that is inside my packet**? Or need I to look for the hexadecimal code of the header and compare it with the ARP one? This should be *extremely inefficient*, since I would have to do it with each packet I receive in my simulation. (And since I've It not done, I'm not sure that It's the correct way nor just possible).

Thanks for reading

Comment: I saw you weren't getting any responses, so I'm offering a bounty to help you get the answer you need.

Comment: Can you post the content of such a package in question?

Comment: I could be able to create it, let me simulate it. But it's not a package alone, I explain. I've two devices connect through WiFi. I'm simulating their communication (between sinkpacket and bulksendapplication). I repeat it with several distances between them. There's a point were errors are too high in order to let "big" packets (500B) to go through, but ARP (about 64B) can still. So if I run this simulation and generate the pcap file, I can check they're ARPs. I needed this for a practice, so I filter them by size eventually. But still don't know if there's another (and more correct) way.

Comment: So, do you still want me to give the packets? Are they relevant? How should I post it? Entire packet string in a pastebin?

Comment: Btw, thank you very much for your interest and help Cory!

Comment: @BtcSources: No problem. Given that the bounty is ending soon, can you review the [following answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27843639/74757) to see if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

GetUid() is not relevant; it is merely an internal ID for packet data structures that has no relation to the protocols being carried.

In ns-3, packets are serialized in network byte order into Buffer objects, analogous to Linux kernel skbuffs.  A brute force way to inspect the packet contents is to deserialize (copy) the packet contents into a separate buffer, and pick through the bytes, as you mentioned.  However, there are better ways.

If you are at the Wifi layer, and you want to learn whether the packet you have is an ARP packet, there are two main ways you can learn this.  First, you can inspect the headers of the packet.  If you are at the point in the stack where only the LlcSnapHeader has been added by the WifiNetDevice, you can try to peek the header and look at the protocol number (stored in the Type field).  Given a Ptr pkt, you can try:

```
LlcSnapHeader llc;
pkt->PeekHeader (llc);
if (llc.GetType () == 0x0806)
  {
    // found an ARP packet
  }
```

However, note that if you are at a place in the stack where various frame types are being used, not all packets will have an LlcSnapHeader, so peeking such as above may not be reliable, or you may need to check other possibilities.  Also, in cases where you are not fortunate enough that the header you care about is at the very front of the packet, keep in mind that it is not expensive to copy the Packet and remove headers from the packet copy (essentially popping them off the stack) to get at the header you want.

A second technique is possible if you have enabled Packet metadata in the simulation.  this is a data structure that contains metadata about all of the headers and trailers that have been added, and can be returned to the client as a linked list that can be scanned for header information.  By default, it is disabled in simulations for performance reasons, but can be enabled by calling this at the beginning of the main() program:

```
Packet::EnablePrinting ();
```

and then using the BeginItem() iterator of the Packet class (see the ns-3 Doxygen).  There are no good example programs using this as far as I know, but a test suite exists in src/network/test that may provide hints.

Comment: Not sure if I understood it at all. Then, if I'm receiving the packet when a phy trace is thrown, LLC should be just above and I would be able to use the first method? I've run it, and got that protocol of every sigle packet was "0". I'm doing the check at the Rx callback of PhyRxEnd.

Answer (score 0):

I simply use the packet size to filter ARP packets. I think using the if condition `if (packet->GetSize () != 58)` in your callback is the simplest solution for you.